# Concatenate a vector in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm trying to concatenate a vector into a string in order to insert it into a get call.

Previously in my code I use the following:

```
.exec(http("request_11")
        .get("/api/data/users/${userId}")
        .headers(headers_3)
        .check(jsonPath("$..users[0].links.orgRoles[*]").findAll.saveAs("orgRoles")))
```

Which gives me an `orgRoles` session variable of:

> Vector(b2b5fb81-4025-48a5-9890-a6ec7d64f317, 744db047-1477-4bb6-9c55-70071ce41cb8, 423b0b07-7bfa-416a-9b95-cc1d75d7d781)

I'd then like to use this concatenated session variable like so:

```
.exec(http("request_50")
        .get("/api/data/orgRoles/${orgRoles}")
```

Which would, in effect, do the following get call:

```
.exec(http("request_50")
        .get("/api/data/orgRoles/b2b5fb81-4025-48a5-9890-a6ec7d64f317,744db047-1477-4bb6-9c55-70071ce41cb8,423b0b07-7bfa-416a-9b95-cc1d75d7d781")
        .headers(headers_3))
```

I'm brand new to Gatling and Scala, and have done a ton of research. I found the following [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/mSYloBEDStk) which offers that

```
session => session("itemIds").validate[Seq[String]].map(_.mkString(","))
```

is the right approach. In turn, I've tried to manipulate the session variable with the following:

```
...
.exec { session => 
        session("orgRoles").map(_.mkString(","))
    }
.exec(http("request_50")
    .get("/api/data/orgRoles/${orgRoles}")
    .headers(headers_3))
...
```

Yet end up with the error:

> value mkString is not a member of io.gatling.core.session.SessionAttribute

Any suggestions on moving forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is because by:

```
session("orgRoles")
```

you are calling `Session.apply` method at session instance ([for more see source code](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/session/Session.scala#L82)). The `apply` method returns `SessionAttribute` instance, which has following methods:

```
// Use when you are certain that key exists in session, otherwise you'll get exception which you has to handle
def as[T: NotNothing]: T
// Use when you want to handle also not existing key and you can react to `None` case
def asOption[T: TypeCaster: ClassTag: NotNothing]: Option[T]
// Use when you want to code against success path and use combinators provided by `Validation`
def validate[T: TypeCaster: ClassTag: NotNothing]: Validation[T]
```

Each servers different purpose (see comments). All above mentioned methods of `SessionAttribute` are just [getters from session](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/session_api.html#getting-attributes). Their only purpose is to provide you a value of the key stored in session in any form.

Only after getting the value you can do anything with it. The safest bet is to use `validate` method which provides common combinators (used in all Scala collections) `map` and `flatMap` to manipulate the value when it exist. You can find more about `Validation` concept [here](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/validation.html). Hence your code should look like:

```
// Just getting from session and concatenating
session => session("orgRoles").validate[Seq[String]].map( _.mkString(",") )
// also storing back to session
session => session.set("orgRoles", session("orgRoles").validate[Seq[String]].map( _.mkString(",") ))
```

This is also what you already wrote above. But you are already using `check` DSL method and thus you can use `transform()` directly in your first call as:

```
.exec(
   http("request_11")
     .get("/api/data/users/${userId}")
     .headers(headers_3)
     .check(
       jsonPath("$..users[0].links.orgRoles[*]")
         .findAll
         .transform( _.mkString(",") )
         .saveAs("orgRoles")
     )
)
```

It's straightforward, easier to follow and there is no temporary save to `Session`. Even the function which you put to `transform` is easier, while it is defined as `A => B` thus plain transformation. Check-out more about transforming [here](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/http/http_check.html#transforming).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling the toString or maybe groupHierarchy?

```
session => session("itemIds").validate[Seq[String]].map(_.toString.mkString(","))
session => session("itemIds").validate[Seq[String]].map(_.groupHierarchy.mkString(","))
```

take a look at:  https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/session/Session.scala

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it with this:

```
.exec(session => 
            session.set("orgRolesConcat", session("orgRoles").as[Seq[String]].mkString(",")))
```